# Error related to Aptitude appears at sudo apt upgrade

Tags: apt, aptitude

when entering the command `$ sudo apt upgrade` I receive the following output.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
E: Could not get lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock. It is held by process 95610 (aptitude)
N: Be aware that removing the lock file is not a solution and may break your system.
E: Unable to lock directory /var/cache/apt/archives/
```

I am afraid if the two error codes influence the system performance in the long term.

I was installing the aptitude function but unfortunately I cannot recall the command I entered that caused the issue.

Comment: It seems aptitude is running. Try to kill it by `kill -9 95610` and try again.

Comment: Aptitude is running and blocking updates. Close it and all should be OK.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/) is another process using it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process)